# How to write this query in JPA

Tags: jpa

How to write this query in JPA?

```
select  sol.ID_UNICA, sol.version  
from  uexdfr01.SOLUTION  sol   
  join  
 (select   solution4_.ID_UNICA,  max(solution4_.version) as maxVersion
   from uexdfr01.ORDER order3_   
inner join uexdfr01.SOLUTION solution4_ on   order3_.ID_SOLUTION=solution4_.ID_SOLUTION
where solution4_.ID_UNICA in   (130,139,143,129,126,128,141,121,124,131)group by  solution4_.ID_UNICA) as  groupedtt   
on sol.ID_UNICA = groupedtt.ID_UNICA 
   AND sol.version = groupedtt.maxVersion*
```

Comment: JPQL queries use entities. You haven't posted any entities. You haven't posted what relations these entities have. In fact you've made no effort to say WHAT you have tried. Post all of that in the QUESTION, and then people may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about db relationships use createNativeQuery and pass your query inside parenthesis.

```
Query selectRecords = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sqlQuery.toString());
```

Returned values are type of Objects so make sure to assign them in List as following way..

`List<Object[]> data= selectRecords.getResultList()`;